# To what extend that Object to/from JSON/XML (un)marshaling can break

Tags: java, json, marshalling, xstream, unmarshalling

I've been thinking for these two JSON library:

- Google Gson
- JSON.Simple
- XStream

Google Gson is pretty awesome, it can serialize class object that have no-args constructor. JSON.Simple is neat to with a very simple to use API. However to what extent these JSON/Object mapping libraries can break, i.e. cannot marshal object anymore, both in terms of serialization and deserialization.

For the following scenarios:

- Nesting of classes, i.e. classes within classes, and the like
- Very long String values in classes within classes and those sort of things
- Size of object, i.e. objects containing huge bytes

What are the scenarios where marshaling *can't take it anymore* or *bang against the wall*?

I'm just thinking out loud here to understand what could go wrong when using these kinds of frameworks as a backbone for my applications. And how we can foresee the potential quirks that could happen.

**Update:**

And with regards to portability, to what extent we can reply on (un)marshaling, especially when dealing with object distribution. For example, A "serialized" object is sent over another machine, with different CPU, JVM, etc and that it is intended to be "deserialized" and used in some way.

Comment: you can also have a look at genson http://code.google.com/p/genson/, it is easy to use, provides streaming api/databinding, can deserialize even if there is no default ctr and much more

Answer (score 0):

There are two limits here: the limits of JSON, and the limits of your marshalling software.

The first one is obvious:

- JSON cannot serialize graphs. There is only 'content' in JSON, which means a circular relationship cannot be created in JSON.

An example in code:

```
class Bar { List<Drink> menu = new ArrayList<Drink>(); }
class Drink { List<Bar> servedIn = new ArrayList<Drink>(); }

public void main() {
    Bar b = new Bar();
    Drink whiskey = new Drink();
    b.menu.add(whiskey);
    whiskey.servedIn.add(b);
    serialize(b);
    // a naive serialization will keep serializing
    // a smart serialization will not include the Drink.servedIn field or throw an error
}
```

The second limits depend on your marhsalling software and how it is constructed. Simply put, you will need twice the memory of your object graph: once for serialised form, and once for unserialised form. Some parsers are smarter, and provide streaming which reduces the memory requirements.

Comment: So in other words, if I have a a class Foo with field type of class Bar, then at runtime, I did: Bar bar = new Bar(); foo.bar = bar then assuming that we put values in the bar object, that would not be serialized. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @xybrek - There are XML & JSON-binding frameworks that support bidirectional relationships.  Here is an example of how we do it in EclipseLink MOXy:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/03/moxys-xmlinversereference-is-now-truly.html

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan Thanks for the link, I did not know that! Quick note: this will only work for relationships where the relationship can be modeled using 'containment'. For many-to-many relationships or one-to-one / one-to-many relationships where no clear containment tree can be estabilished, this will not work. Example: Family Tree with 'Cousin' relationship.